# What does "..." mean when next to a parameter in a go function declaration?

Tags: go

I was going through some code written in Google's Go language, and I came across this:

```
func Statusln(a ...interface{})
func Statusf(format string, a ...interface{})
```

I don't understand what the `...` means. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It means that you can call Statusln with a [variable number of arguments](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters). For example, calling this function with:

```
Statusln("hello", "world", 42)
```

Will assign the parameter a the following value:

```
a := []interface{}{"hello", "world", 42}
```

So, you can iterate over this slice a and process all parameters, no matter how many there are. A good and popular use-case for variadic arguments is for example fmt.Printf() which takes a format string and a variable number of arguments which will be formatted according to the format string.

Comment: FYI. If you already have multiple args in a slice, apply them to a variadic function using `func(slice...)` like `Statusln(a...)` in the above example.

Answer (score 7):

They are *variadic functions*. These functions accept a variable number of arguments.

#### Example

The `sums` function below accepts multiple integers:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func sum(nums ...int) {
    fmt.Print(nums, " ")
    total := 0
    for _, num := range nums {
        total += num
    }
    fmt.Println(total)
}

func main() {

    sum(1, 2)
    sum(1, 2, 3)

    nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    sum(nums...)
}
```

#### For more info

- [Go By Example: Variadic Functions](https://gobyexample.com/variadic-functions)
- [Wikipedia: Variadic Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)

Answer (score 6):

It is variable length argument

```
func Printf(format string, v ...interface{}) (n int, err error) {
```

Take for example this signature. Here we define that we have one string to print, but this string can be [interpolated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_Interpolation) with variable number of things (of arbitrary type) to substitude (actually, I took this function from fmt package):

```
fmt.Printf("just i: %v", i)
fmt.Printf("i: %v and j: %v",i,j)
```

As you can see here, with variadic arguments, one signature fits all lengths.

Moreover, you can specify some exact type like `...int`.

Comment: what does that mean? that the number of arguments is not specified?

Comment: @Chaos Yeah, exactly. Such a function can accept between 0 to n number of arguments and called a Variadic function.